# Handle touch event on Edittext and Relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-relativelayout

**-** I have container `RelativeLayout`, in that container i added `EditText` programatically by touching on the container [on ACTION_DOWN].

**-** And i have also provided the functionality to drag the `EditText` on the `RelativeLayout`.

**-** The problem i am facing at present is that, **i am not able to differentiate the invent triggering the touch for editing and dragging.**

**-** Can anyone please help me out of this situation..........

Comment: Set an onClick and determine the clicked View by: public void onClick(View view) 
{
    switch (view.getId())
    {
        case R.id.editText1:
            //do stuff
        break;
    }
}

Comment: You can also set in the layout of the `EditText` the following: `android:onClick="editTextClicked"` - which should be defined as a method like `public void editTextClicked(View v) {}`.